# How to generate HTML from a winform (c#) application

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I need to create a log file containing HTML (tables, etc). It seems that HtmlTextWriter is not supported in plain winforms applications, it is intended for ASP.NET. Is this in fact the case, and if so, what classes are available to generate HTML? I was trying to use FileStream/StreamWriter but it chokes on "illegal characters".

Comment: HTML files are simple text files. There is no reason you wouldn't be able to use FileStream/StreamWriter. Can you give us more informations about the illegal characters error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`HtmlTextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx) is available to WinForms apps, just not by default. You have to add a reference to `System.Web` in the WinForms project to be able to use it.

Comment: This sounds right, but I wonder if there's a problem when using the client profile?

Comment: @DamianPowell - I'm not sure about that. The OP may have to change up their target framework.

Comment: I tried updating the framework from Client to v4. I am still not able to add a reference to System.Web.UI; doesn't appear in the list nor does it allow me to add it by typing it in. Doing a search I find no dll named System.Web.UI. What am I missing? An reference to HtmlTextWriter in the code causes a compile error when just including System.Web.

Comment: Once I added System.Web to the references by browsing to the DLL, I can add a using for System.Web.UI. Problem solved.